# Why does running a virtual machine give me a higher FPS on video games?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-player

So here i have an odd case.

If i'm playing GTA San Andreas i usually get an FPS of around 30-35. However when i start a virtual machine (VMWare player with only one core and 1gb ram) on core i7, the FPS skyrockets to an almost constant 60FPS.

One theory i have is that running the VM might be causing the processor to stay in higher performance mode for longer.

What could be causing this odd behavior?

Comment: Just to be clear: you run the game aside from VM, not inside it, right?

Comment: Are you running it on the IGP? There's a article here with a user having a similar experience (The last poster) - http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2177695/game-runs-faster-vmware.html

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yep, on the host

Comment: @Carrein I am running the game on the host, not inside the VM.

Comment: What hardware do you have?

Comment: @aventurin Core i7 2600, 6GB Ram and a Radeon HD 7750 video card.